# Statistics in print composer Qgis

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I would like to add a table with some statistics in the print composer.

I want to show the rate of feature for a specific value. Let say I have a "Existing" field with 'Yes' or 'No' properties. I want to add a table with Y% Yes / X% No

I tried to use the expression dialog but with no success.

For info: I am on mac OSx and can't use SQL requests as there is an important but since 2 years with this.

Comment: What expression did you try? This should be simple enough to do, but we'll need to see what you've already attempted to see where it went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a label to the print composer, and insert an expression using the aggregate function.
[image]

For example, to calculate the percentage of "yes" values in the field "Existing" use this expression:

> aggregate('mylayer','count',  ' ',"Existing" = 'yes') / layer_property('mylayer','feature_count') *100

These label settings:

[image]

Give you a label that looks like this:

[image]

For other types of calculations, check out the other functions available in the expression editor.

Comment: Thank you that is a great answer ! Would it be possible to calculate percentage based on $lengh of each lines?
And is it possible to have a 1 number precision? (Only one number after comma)

Comment: Try the round() function for specifying 1 digit precision.

Comment: The round () function is perfect for the digit precision. But I'am still facing difficulties with the calculation of % of length and not % of the number of lines. My layer is composed if road and I would like to know the proportion of the total length which have a specific value.

Comment: I answered the question you posted, which was how to add "some statistics" to the print composer. Please accept this answer, and post a **new** question for any **specific statistics** that you want help calculating.

Comment: Got it. I have accepted your answer and will post a new question. Thanks